# Automate Delphi 2010 project build with MSBuild

Tags: delphi, command-line, msbuild, compilation

I'm looking to compile my Delphi 2010 project using MSBuild, but something isn't right, I just couldn't make MSBuild to compile my project.

I tried this command line:

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" "C:\MyProject\Myapp.dproj" /t:Release

and this:

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" "C:\MyProject\Myapp.dproj" /p:Configuration=Release /t:Release

But MSBuild won't recognize my build configuration!

I also changed [ **rsvars.bat** ] but it didn't work!

```
@SET BDS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0
@SET BDSCOMMONDIR=C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0
@SET FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
@SET FrameworkVersion=v4.0.30319
@SET FrameworkSDKDir=
@SET PATH=%FrameworkDir%;%FrameworkSDKDir%;%PATH%
@SET LANGDIR=EN
```

The MSBuild error is:

```
C:\MyProject\Myapp.dproj : error MSB4057: The target "Release" does
not exist in the project.
```

Any help to get me build my app with MSBuild would be greatly appreciated.

(Yes, I'm fully aware of tools like FinalBuilder, I just want to learn how to do this with MSBuild)

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, OK (1) I changed rsvars.bat back (but still can't compile :(), (2) DOS doesn't recognize msbuild without full path.

Comment: If you run the rsvars.bat file before running msbuild the windows console (which is not the same as DOS, as a side note) will recognize a plain call to 'msbuild.exe' as rsvars.bat modifies the PATH variable (see line 6). You can also permanently edit the environment variables - that way you don't have to run rsvars.bat every time.

Comment: 2. It certainly does recognise msbuild, if you run rsvars.bat before calling msbuild. Read the docs. They explain all of this.

Comment: Doh! Yes, I see now, I run the rsvars.bat (don't laugh! I was double-clicking on it before!) and now Chris's line works!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, I modified the PATH variable, but somehow it only works if I run the commandline inside CMD running as administrator...should I just restart or something?

Comment: You don't need to be admin to build. After changing PATH did you start a new cmd window? You need to do that to pick up the new PATH var.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I did. Running the msbuild result in a message box telling me that "C:\Users\Admin\msbuild.exe is not a valid Win32 application." and then a message is written in the console telling me that "Access is denied."

If I run CMD as admin, MSBuild works just fine.

Comment: You need to delete the bogus file `C:\Users\Admin\msbuild.exe`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're a genius! I really don't know where does this bogus file comes from, but it did the trick!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to switch the parameters. The target parameter (/t) tells MSBuild which target to create.
This can be either 'Make', 'Clean' or 'Build' (or a combination of those - seperate them with ';' in this case).

The property parameter (/p) forwards properties to the actual compiler. You can specify for example the configuration using `/p:config=`

So if you want to clean and then build a project using the release configuration, specify the paramters like this:

```
msbuild.exe "/t:Clean;Build" "/p:config=Release" Myapp.dproj
```

Comment: Thank you, Chris but now I'm getting this:

Comment: Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]

Build started 2/17/2012 20:37:11 PM.
Project "D:\_Software\test.dproj" on node 1 (Clean;Build target(s))
.
D:\_Software\test.dproj : error MSB4057: The target "Clean" does no
t exist in the project.
Done Building Project "D:\_Software\test.dproj" (Clean;Build target
(s)) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"D:\_Software\test.dproj" (Clean;Build target) (1) ->
  D:\_Software\test.dproj : error MSB4057: The target "Clean" does
not exist in the project.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Comment: @David Heffernan I'm using powershell, and it seperates commands by semicolons. That makes it necessary to put quotes around them. The standard console does not require this though

Comment: @chris alternative is to use /t twice (/t:clean /t:build) or use a back tick to escape the ; (/clean`;build)

Answer (score 1):

Change `/p:Configuration=Release` to `/p:config=Release`