# Error Target clean does not exist in the project msbuild error while building delphi projects

Tags: delphi, msbuild, tfsbuild

We are building delphi projects using the msbuild tasks in VNext builds, they were running successfully until the TFS build agents were update to latest version 2.112.0, following is the error message:  Error MSB4057: The target "Clean" does not exist in the project. Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1' Any inputs to solve these errors would be helpful.

Comment: *.targets import are available, the tasks were running successfully until we upgraded the TFS build agent to latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you build the project from command line in the build server?

Please make sure you specified the parameters correctly.
The property parameter (/p) forwards properties to the actual compiler. You can specify for example the configuration using /p:config=

So if you want to clean and then build a project using the release configuration, specify the paramters like this:

```
msbuild.exe "/t:Clean" "/t:Build" "/p:config=Release" Myapp.dproj
```

Please reference this thread [Automate Delphi 2010 project build with MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334001/automate-delphi-2010-project-build-with-msbuild) 
And Thomas's answer in [this article](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=712944) .

Comment: rsvars.bat file had be be executed prior to executing the command line msbuild command

Comment: I'm using a Azure build pipeline and don't specify and command line.